# showing multiple images in imageviewer through loop

Tags: java, android, android-imageview, android-image

I want to show multiple images in my imageView I want to do this by using a for loop, but my image view only shows the last image.

I have tried Thread.sleep and sleep functions too but they didn't work

```
for(int i=0;i<=3;i++){
                try {

                    pic = picText.getText().toString();
                    String photoPath = "sdcard/Pictures/" + pic + i + ".jpg";
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(photoPath));
                    sleep(1000);
                } catch (Exception ex) {

                }}
```

I expect to get all the images one after other, the delay is given in sleep() function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show multiple images in a imageView one after another with left to right flip effect repeatedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27167866/show-multiple-images-in-a-imageview-one-after-another-with-left-to-right-flip-ef)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Thread.sleep(1000)` which pause the execution of current thread for specified time in milliseconds.

Comment: I have tried it too, but it works same as sleep() and only puts the delay and displays the image whose path is passed at the end.

Comment: Check whether photo paths are different for each iteration. log the photopath inside the loop.

Comment: all the photos are in the same folder of Pictures and are named like abc0, abc1, abc2, abc3

Answer (score 0):

Get all the imagepath in array or ArrayList and then use a handler and timertask

> Timer t;    Handler handler;   Runnable update; handler = new
>   Handler();
>           update = new Runnable() {
>               @Override
>               public void run() {
>
> ```
>             //load photo
>         }
>     };
>     t = new Timer();
>            t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
>                @Override
>                public void run() {
>                    handler.post(update);
>                }
>            }, 0, 5000);
> ```

```
Note if its showing last image, redirect counter to 1st image. Hope this helps
```